# Rails destroy model not deleting migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I originally had a migration called CreateUsers that had a table already.

Due to my stupidity, i thought i had to do a rails generate migration in order to add indexes to the table. When i did a migration it was this:

```
rails generate migration CreateUsers years:integer
```

So it creates a migration with the timestamp and so on,  and i tried deleting using this

```
 rails d migration migration_filename
```

Its giving me some error regarding this

```
/Users/giowong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb:57:in `validate_file_name!': Illegal name for migration file: 20140219230444_create_create_users.rb (ActiveRecord::IllegalMigrationNameError)
```

In the schema.rb table stll exists

should i manually delete both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to run `rails d` against the filename, but against the migration name you had in your generate.

Try:  `rails d migration CreateUsers`

In order to drop the table, you'll want to `rollback` your migration as well:

`rake db:rollback STEP=1`

`STEP=1` assumes this was the last migration run.  You also may need to prepend `bundle exec` if you're using bundler in your app.

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it. Quick question.... I just did a new migration and timestamp was not included in the table... should i be worried?

Comment: Did you include `t.timestamps` or a similar line in your migration?  You could add this with another migration to the same table...

Comment: i thought t.timestamps will be automatically generated everytime you do a new migration?

Comment: I believe that only works with model and scaffold migrations.

Comment: is there a way to add timestamps in the rails generate migration? Sorry as you can see im clearly new to rails

Comment: Welcome to Rails!!! :)  As far as I know, there isn't a way to do this using the generator.  But before you run the migration, you can modify the migration file to add timestamps.